# Convergence of a parametrised semigroup on a Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}, \,\, s>n/2$ and denote $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the Sobolev space. 
Let $u :(0, 1] \to H^s$ be bounded and denote

$$f(x) := \left({\rm e}^{x \Delta + (x^2 \Delta^2 + \Delta)^{\frac 12}}- {\rm e}^{{\rm i}\sqrt{-\Delta}}\right)u(x).$$

I wonder whether we can prove that $\lim_{x\to 0} \|f(x)\|_{H^s} = 0.$

My attempt is to use the dominated convergence theorem on

$$\|f(x)\|^2_{H^s} = \int(1+|\xi|^2)^s\left|{\rm e}^{-x |\xi|^2 + (x^2|\xi|^4 -|\xi|^2)^{\frac 12}}- {\rm e}^{{\rm i}|\xi|}\right|^2 |\widehat{u(x)}(\xi)|^2 d\xi .$$
It is clear that $\left|{\rm e}^{-x |\xi|^2 + (x^2 |\xi|^4 -|\xi|^2)^{\frac 12}}- {\rm e}^{{\rm i}|\xi|}\right| \leq2.$ Howewer, does the boundness of $u(x)$ imply the integrability of
$$\xi \mapsto (1+|\xi|^2)^s \sup_{x} |\widehat{u(x)}(\xi)|?$$

Thank you for any hint

Comment: did you see my answer below? grace period ends soon

Comment: I just wanted to check before commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think $\lim_{x \to 0} ||f(x)||_{H^s} = 0$ is true (in general). All we know about $u$ is that $\int (1+|\xi|^2)^s|\widehat{u(x)}(\xi)|^2d\xi$ is bounded. So we can have $||u(x)||_{H^s} = 1$ for each $x$ and $\int_{x^{-100} < \xi < 2x^{-100}} (1+|\xi|^2)^s|\widehat{u(x)}(\xi)|^2d\xi = 1$ if we want (I want this). And then $$\int(1+|\xi|^2)^s\left|{\rm e}^{-x |\xi|^2 + (x^2|\xi|^4 -|\xi|^2)^{\frac 12}}- {\rm e}^{{\rm i}|\xi|}\right|^2 |\widehat{u(x)}(\xi)|^2 d\xi = \int_{x^{-100} < \xi < 2x^{-100}} (1+|\xi|^2)^s\left|{\rm e}^{-x |\xi|^2 + (x^2|\xi|^4 -|\xi|^2)^{\frac 12}}- {\rm e}^{{\rm i}|\xi|}\right|^2 |\widehat{u(x)}(\xi)|^2 d\xi.$$ The whole point is that $\left|{\rm e}^{-x |\xi|^2 + (x^2|\xi|^4 -|\xi|^2)^{\frac 12}}- {\rm e}^{{\rm i}|\xi|}\right|^2$ will basically be $\left|1-e^{i|\xi|}\right|^2$ as $x \downarrow 0$ for $\xi \in [x^{-100},2x^{-100}]$, so we end up with $$\int_{x^{-100} < \xi < 2x^{-100}} (1+|\xi|^2)^s\left|1-e^{i|\xi|}\right|^2 |\widehat{u(x)}(\xi)|^2 d\xi,$$ which has absolutely no reason to tend to $0$. If you wanted me to be more rigorous, instead of just restricting $\xi$ to $[x^{-100},2x^{-100}]$, we could restrict to very small balls around $\xi$ that satisfy $e^{i\xi} = -1$, so that $|1-e^{i|\xi|}| \ge 1.9$, say, and then we end up with $||f(x)||_{H_s}^2 \ge 1.9$ for each $x$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. If I don't miss any thing, the answer won't change in the case where $u$ is constant with respect to $x$ ??

Comment: I have no idea where you got that from...

Comment: I chose $u$ such that, for each $x$, $\widehat{u(x)}$ is supported on $\xi$ in the range $[x^{-100},2x^{-100}]$.

Comment: Ok, now this more clear to me. Then, the  question is:   can we chose $u(x)$ as you claimed ?  I tried to think about a counterexample where $\widehat{u(x)}$ is almost as you claimed $u(x,t) = e^{(-t^2 + i x t)}$ but this is not bounded in $H^1(\mathbb{R})$ for example.

Comment: I mean just use fourier inversion. $H^s$ is equivalent to $\int(1+|\xi|^2)^s|\widehat{u(x)}(\xi)|^2 d\xi < \infty$. So just take any $u$ satisfying that (with my conditions added) and then use fourier inversion.

Comment: OK. this is better now. Thank you again. I highly  appreciate  this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106355/discussion-between-a-pi-and-mathworker21).